# Plastic anchors in concrete?

Tags: concrete, anchor

Can I use plastic anchors to fasten a 35lb mirror to a concrete wall? I need two screws.

Apparently I have to clarify:
I go online, I try to research what works best in concrete, I see half the sites saying plastic anchors are fine, the other half saying one must ONLY use metal anchors. I am trying to get the opinion of people who know more than me. If this somehow contravenes the way stack exchange should be used feel free to just delete the question. I don't know how else to clarify this.

Comment: Are the anchors specified for use in concrete and is their allowed weight high enough for a 35' mirror?

Comment: They are specified, and their weight claims to be beyond 35lbs. But I just read two different places that said plastic anchors are not reliable for long term use. Could they maybe have been referring to far hanging far more heavy things? Like maybe light construction applications? Because otherwise I don't know how these anchors I have could legally get away with saying what they say.

Comment: @tinpanalley without knowing what you read, how do you expect us to answer?

Comment: @SolarMike I would expect, forgive my short sightedness, that one would be capable of offering possible ideas by process of elimination. I cook. If you told me a friend made me something that was a savoury soup without cream but was still thick I could still more or less guess at what it was without having to see the recipe.

Comment: So even matchsticks work well - often better than plastic cr*p…

Comment: @SolarMike As you can see, even in the replies to my own question, the idea of plastic vs metal is not unanimous.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean what Brits would call rawlplugs? [no matter who made them]

[image: rawlplugs]

If so, then so long as you use correct sizes in a hard enough substrate & drill the holes neatly, they're as strong as the shearing force of the screw itself. If you're unsure, move up a size or two on your plugs & screws.

They tend to be colour-coded [but not *all* manufacturers use the same colour] with brown being the largest. If you need more support than that you're getting into wall-anchor territory, but not for a mirror.

Half the UK must be held up by rawlplugs ;)

[image: multicolour plugs]

Comment: Interesting actually seeing Rawl brand plugs, thanks for the pic! Here in the US, when we buy them, they're individually molded and don't come on a tree like that. In some ways ours are easier, but yours are harder to loose...

Comment: @FreeMan - some copy brands don't come on a tree, but the tree itself is dual-purpose [& must be simpler to manufacture, I guess]. It has marked holes for drill size & min & max screw size too. Easy peasy ;)

Comment: Handy indeed! Now I wish we could get 'em on our side of the pond. Of course, I'm not a big user of them, but if I were...

Comment: @FreeMan - maybe the US is a tougher market - & in a sweeping generalisation, the UK is made of bricks, the US is made of wood & drywall. We don't have a single wood-framed/drywall wall in the entire building here, even the inside walls are all brick. Different on newer builds of course, where corner-cutting has become the name of the game.

Comment: Just wanted to say I love this conversation about UK vs NA anchors/fasteners. I went a little off topic in another question here and got my ass handed to me for my comment being irrelevant. Anyway, very interesting. As far as my question goes, I'm getting more and more the impression that wedge anchors or expansion bolts would be better. Not because the 35lb mirror needs it but because it'll just grip better and safer in the hole.

Comment: Glad you're enjoying it;) The UK really is held up by rawlplugs, it's the only fastener I use here, in masonry. You *really* don't need expansion bolts for 35lb. Aside from the fact that all the force is vertical, ie, across the screw & meaning the screw itself is actually the weakest part, you couldn't pull rawlplugs out with any hand tool you own, if they're done properly. I used to install TV monitors in hospitals with them, 4 plugs & screws into brick or concrete, our base test was to do pull-ups on the mounting bar, with 15" leverage.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think the concern from people is that this isn't super polished car park concrete, it is a tiny bit more crumbly than that and that plastic ones won't hold over time. But I don't know which is why I'm asking. Because you'd be surprised how vague the info online is. As I was saying to the other person here, even here in the answers to my own question there are differing opinions about metal vs plastic. And I'm just a novice DIY person trying to figure out where the discrepancy lies. Thanks, though.

Comment: I think what you will find is familiarity vs unfamiliarity. The UK uses a lot of Rawlplugs… in anything. Brand-new concrete, 100-year-old crumbly brick & anything in between. It's like the US uses a lot of Wago clips [or worse, wire nuts] for electricals, whereas most Brits wouldn't touch them with a barge-pole. We have terminal strip. Tried & tested, lasts probably centuries, costs pence. The US has so much drywall that I'd bet most people would never have occasion to ever use a rawlplug. It leads to 'FUD". Fear, uncertainty & doubt ;)